# How to convert string to date in SQL for all the items in the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently, one of the column in the SQL table contains date in `DMMYYYY` format and the column dtype is `VARCHAR`. But I would like to convert it into in date dtype format i.e. `DD/MM/YYYY` format

Current format:

```
8012005
9012005
10012005
```

Required format:

```
08/01/2005
09/01/2005
10/01/2005
```

My Attempt

```
SELECT [serial]
  ,[srn]
  ,[ticker]
  ,[series]
  ,[QT]
  ,[DQ]
  ,[DQ/QT]
  ,[TIMESTAMP]
  FROM [Indexer].[dbo].[EquityNSEDAT]

SELECT CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, '%D/%m/%y');
```

Comment: You *really* need to fix your design here, not `CONVERT` the value in a `SELECT`. Why are you storing a date value in a string based data type and not a `date`?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is your table here, you need to fix your design. To do that you need to change the data type of your column from a (presumably) string based data type to a `date` data type. I also assume you have bad data, and so retain that bad data in a new column. You'll need to review that data after and fix it manually.

Firstly, fixing your design. This changes your string from am ambiguous value to the an ISO format (`yyyyMMdd`), then changes the data type of your columns:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourDate varchar(8) NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES ('8012005'),
       ('9012005'),
       ('10012005'),
       ('31112005'),
       ('4132005');
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD BadDate varchar(8) NULL;
GO

UPDATE YT
SET BadDate = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date,FD.FormattedDate) IS NULL THEN YT.YourDate END,
    YourDate = CONVERT(varchar(8),TRY_CONVERT(date,FD.FormattedDate,112),112)
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(RIGHT('00000000' + YT.YourDate,8)))PD(PaddedDate)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONCAT(RIGHT(PD.PaddedDate,4), SUBSTRING(PD.PaddedDate,3,2),LEFT(PD.PaddedDate,2))))FD(FormattedDate);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourDate date NULL;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
--Get bad data
SELECT BadDate
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE BadDate IS NOT NULL;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

After you've done that, to get the value *displayed* as you want, configure this in your **presentation layer**, not the SQL layer; leave the data type as a `date` in your SQL layer.

Comment: I've data worth 6.5 million rows, so I can't manually put values into values ()......any other way?

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying, @Raj . Both `VALUES` table construct are set based; the first uses `YT.YourDate` which would, unsurprisingly, be *your date [Column]*, and the second uses the column returned from the first `VALUES` table construct. There no need to define 6.5 millions `UPDATE` statements; the one above will do it all.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a date in DMMYYYY format (e.g. "8012005") to DD/MM/YYYY format (e.g. "08/01/2005") in a SQL query,  use the CONVERT() function with the appropriate style parameter.

In your case, the query below converts the TIMESTAMP column from DMMYYYY format to DD/MM/YYYY format:

```
SELECT [serial]
  ,[srn]
  ,[ticker]
  ,[series]
  ,[QT]
  ,[DQ]
  ,[DQ/QT]
  ,CONVERT(DATE, TIMESTAMP, 105) AS TIMESTAMP
FROM [Indexer].[dbo].[EquityNSEDAT]
```

Comment: It got errored out with the following message.. Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string